# How can I change PHP ini settings from within a shell script?

Tags: php, linux, configuration

How can I set ini settings within a PHP script?

php.ini isn't being read and ini_set doesn't work.

Test File:

```
#!usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php

// display_errors is set to false in /etc/php.ini

// This shouldn't display any errors
$test = $foo;

// We can also try
ini_set('display_errors', false);

// This definitely shouldn't display an error
$test = $fum;

?>
```

Output:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: foo in /data/home/___/test.php on line 7
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: fum in /data/home/___/test.php on line 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`-c` option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) allows to specify the php.ini file that should be used.

Comment: Thanks! It is  while since I have been with php. I am now mostly involved in java app development and have recently been alerted to a polyglot vulnerabilty, This is useful in this respect.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try setting error reporting using `error_reporing()` function

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea why ini_set isn't working, but the location of the php.ini file should be shown in a phpinfo(); call - make sure your using the right php.ini (and if not - you may want to symlink the two together)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `-c` option, which allows to specify which php.ini file should be used *(as [Gumbo already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259903/how-can-i-change-php-ini-settings-from-within-a-shell-script/1259966#1259966) -- my answer is just a follow up to his one)*, there is also the possibility to use the `-d` switch, which allows to define one configuration directive *(without having to create a file)* :

```
$ php --help
  ...
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  ...
```

For instance, considering you have a script that only contains this :

```
<?php
var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit'));
die;
```

You can call it this way :

```
$ php ./temp.php
string(4) "128M"
```

And also this way, redefining one configuration directive :

```
$ php -d memory_limit=27M ./temp.php
string(3) "27M"
```

This is really useful when you want to redefine a configuration option for just one script : you don't have to create a new file just for that.

Answer (score 0):

How about (mind the [@](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) character):

<?php

...
// This definitely shouldn't display an error
@$test = $fum;
...

?>

Comment: Pure evilness! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php/960288#960288

Comment: I agree, but I think it's less evil than overriding the entire php.ini file.