# Significance of the @ sign in PHP call

Tags: php

I'm working through some PHP code and cannot figure out what the significance of the @ sign is in this code:

```
    $data = @fread($_socket, 8192);
```

I wasn't able to find many other examples on php.net either that explain what @ does, instead it is just used.

Thanks

Comment: If you see one feel free to tickle torture the author of said code until he cries and screams for mercy. Then gloat.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php

Comment: This one puzzled me briefly the first time I saw it too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The @ suppress the error message that would occur if what is on the right-hand of the @ were to fail.

Here's the link to the php.net page that has full details
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: And it's also the cause of the White Screen of Death (where no error messages are shown or logged, yet the script aborts)...

Comment: It's also a very minor performance hit.  The bytecode compiler has to go out of the way to turn off error reporting just for that one statement, then turn it on again.  Avoid it!

Answer (score 3):

That's the [error control operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), which suppresses error messages.

Answer (score 0):

it's used as a directive to suppress error messages from the call