# What is the difference between the function calls “mail()” and “@mail()”?

Tags: php, function-calls

I am writing a PHP mail function and some examples have `@mail(…)` and others have just `mail(…)`.

What is the difference and which one is best to use?

Cheers

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`@` supresses all warnings/errors, which `mail()` function may throw.

It is not good practice to use "@", because you never know if something doesn't work and also it hits the performance of you PHP application too!

Comment: Brilliant :) That answered my question perfectly

Answer (score 4):

It's the same function but with error suppression

[PHP: Error Control Operators - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Answer (score 3):

`@mail` means you are suppressing any errors that might occur while trying to send the email, see this SO question for more information: [Suppress error with @ operator in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/ddg#138110)

Comment: Cheers. That answers more of my questions. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Error suppression is resource-consuming operation.
It is recommended to call functions without @ and use exceptions/error handling

Comment: I would normally use the non-suppressed functions, but I found the @mail in a site I have been maintaining and didn't want to mess with it too much.