# Is there a way to do this check without two if statements in PHP?

Tags: php, file-exists

i have this if statement

```
if(file_exists( $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.$writabledir.$name) && filemtime($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.$writabledir.$name) < $olddate)  {
```

if the file is there all is well but if the file is not there I get this error

```
 Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for /User....
```

I know I can do an if and then an inner if but is there a better way?

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php

Comment: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=227648.0

Comment: The answer is in the question.

Comment: storing the file name in a temp var would be shorter and more readable

Comment: @Byron Whitlock: I think *you* don't understand short circuit..

Comment: @Byron Whitlock: it *will* be executed. Now think about it, who was on that horse?

Comment: @Alex: that's strange, could you report us the `ls -la` for the directory & file?

Comment: @Byron Whitlock: no it isn't. Would you explain what's wrong with that code? How do you know what the OP wanted to do?

Comment: @yi_H - nothing is wrong with the code. It looks like it should work. Game point yi_H.

Answer (score 0):

If `file_exists` is returning false, then the `filemtime` call should never happen. `&&` is a short-circuiting logical AND in PHP, meaning that if it doesn't need to make the second call (i.e. first part of the logical statement is false, therefore there is no way the whole statement could be true), it won't. There might be something else weird going on in your code.