# what is the @'s purpose in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the use of @ symbol in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php)

I been working with PHP right now but a question pops in my mind what the @ sign means?
I saw it always before method or functions calls. and I try to remove them there is no changes. Can anyone explain me what is the purpose of this @ sign??

```
 @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
```

Comment: It makes you unable to find problems with your scripts.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php

Comment: i didn't notice someone already asked it... thanks everyone... but suppressing errors is not a must during development phase ^_^

Comment: See also "[http://php.net/@](http://php.net/@)". Take care that it only suppresses the error *display* and only with the *default* error handler. Unlike e.g. isset-suppressed messages they can easily be brought back via for example `set_error_handler("var_dump");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, `@` allows you to suppress any errors that arise from the call to a function.

Comment: so this is an alternative in using try and catch statement? where in catch do nothing to suppress the error?

Comment: @Mahan: no, it is not alternative

Comment: `@` suppresses errors, not exceptions. Errors and exceptions are, unfortunately, two completely separate systems in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

It suppresses error messages - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it suppresses error reporting.