# ftp_fget() returns a warning that file doesnt exist... avoid warning without changing error reporting level

Tags: php, ftp

I am connecting to an FTP and downloading a file.  The file name is based on date, so 10242011.csv would be the file the script tries to download today. Sometimes the file does not exist for a day.  I have the following code, but I still receive a php warning:

```
Warning: ftp_fget() [function.ftp-fget]: 10242011.csv: The system cannot find the file specified. in /home/rick/public_html/cron/main.php on line 68
```

Here is the code:

```
if (!ftp_fget($conn, $handle, $ftp_file, FTP_ASCII, 0)) {
    $log[] = array('type' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Unable to download data file (' . $ftp_file . ') from ftp.');
    email_fatal_error(); exit();
} else {            
    $log[] = array('type' => 'success', 'msg' => 'File downloaded.');            
}
```

I know I could just turn of php warings, but I just want to know the "right" way to do this.  Anytime you receive a warning I feel like it could be solved.

Comment: This is *not* the right answer, and should be avoided in general, but you can use the `@` operator to suppress errors for any given operation, e.g. `if (!@ftp_fget($conn, $handle, $ftp_file, FTP_ASCII, 0)) {`. *Please* note that I am *not* telling you to do this, it should be considered a last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first check if the file really exists before using `ftp_fget` function.

You can check with [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

```
if(file_exists($ftp_file))
{
  //do the stuff with ftp_fget
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work, because `$ftp_file` will contain the remote path, relative to the root directory of the FTP user on the remote server. So `file_exists` *may* return true, but only if the file exists on your server...

Comment: @DaveRandom: If you check the PHP documentation for this function , The `Tip` Section shows that it works with the `ftp:`

Comment: Yes, but `$ftp_file` does *not* contain a full `ftp://server/path/to/file` URL, it only contains the file path on the remote system, i.e. just the `/path/to/file` part.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Yes, True, This can be easily changed in script.

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress errors inline if you really don't care about the error by using the `@` character.  This works for the default handler only, other loggers will still log the error.

Example:

```
@ftp_fget(...)
```

will not throw any errors or warnings even though an error may occur.  There is a really good SO post about this behaviour here:
[Suppress error with @ operator in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php)

Comment: That's an option. Explaination about @ is slightly off, as usual. The suppression operator only prevents the error/warning to be shown in PHPs *default* error handler. A custom error or a logging handler would still receive the message and could e.g. log it.