# Save and restore error_reporting level in PHP

Tags: php, error-reporting

I have one weird problem with error_reporting function.

I want to save current error_reporting level, disable error reporting for few lines, and restore it back.
So I have following code:

```
$oldErrorReporting = error_reporting();
error_reporting(0);
//Some code, that will generate warning, or error, that I don't want to show
error_reporting(oldErrorReporting);
```

So, if I remove last line, there are no errors, and everything works fine. But if I add last line, I got error that happen in code while error reporting was turned off.
So, is there any was to clear those errors that happen while error_reporting level was 0, and restore default error reporting level, without those errors that happen while error report was tuned off?

Comment: Is this literally your code? Then you're missing a `$`. Otherwise, do you know of the error suppression operator `@`? Also, what code do you have that triggers errors?

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's just a typo (if so, please *don't* rewrite code for a question, just copy&paste (and remove uneccesssary lines)), but you forgot the `$`-sign in your last line:

```
error_reporting($oldErrorReporting);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it was just type when I pasted code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of code generates warnings? If it is a funciton try instead of lowering the debug level, to suppress the warning itself - write "@" in front of the function name

have a look at:

[Suppress error with @ operator in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php)

Comment: Problem is with imap_open function, and it generate error, in case that connection with imap server fail for any reason, and I want to avoid that, and just inform user if it is possible to connect to IMAP server or not, without error details.
I tried with@ to prevent errors, but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: would you mind posting here importatant parts of code? there are several ways to handle errors...conditions, exceptions etc.