# How to check for multiple urls if exist?

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, fopen

on StackOverflow I found out how to check if just one url exist:

```
if (@fopen($url,'r')){
    echo 'Exist';
}
else {
    echo 'Does not exist';
}
```

How to use this with an array and perhaps with the while loop?

So that I can check for more than 1 URL.

For example, so that it can check 50 URLs?

Comment: Why are you suppressing errors? http://stackoverflow.com/a/960288/871050 Don't suppress errors

Comment: Because fopen will emit a warning if the URI does not exist, and return false. The @ in this case is justified, assuming fopen must be used (I'd use cURL for this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use foreach loop:

```
foreach ($urlsArray as $url) {
  if(@fopen($url,'r')){
    echo 'Exist';
  }
  else {
      echo 'Doesnt exist';
  }
}
```

Comment: How to add an image to every url and output only the image if the url exists?

Comment: @RomanDzialiner, not really sure what you want. You could user echo '<img src="'.$linkToImage.'" />';

Comment: if url1 exists show image1-else nothing, if url2 exists show image2 else nothing, etc.