# code not parsing through a simple google.com test

Tags: php, parsing, screen-scraping

```
    <?php

$file = 'http://www.google.com';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@ $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($file));

echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(2)->nodeValue;

if (0 != $element->length) 
{
    $content = trim($element->item(2)->nodeValue);
    if (empty($content)) 
    {
        $content = trim($element->item(2)->textContent);
    }
    echo $content . "\n";
}

?>
```

im trying to get the inner content of a span tag from google.com's home site.  this code should output the first span tag, but it is not outputting any results?

Comment: Still no luck eh... did you double check that allow_fopen_url is enabled in php.ini

Comment: You are suppressing error messages with the `@`. You should start with removing that.

Comment: Yeah, this calls for basic debugging. What does `loadHTML()` return? What does `file_get_contents()` return? What does `$element` contain? What is `$element->length`s value?

Comment: I think using @ here is correct. He is suppressing any invalid html markup.

Comment: @good4m yeah, but at the same time he is suppressing any errors `file_get_contents()` might be giving him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The is not an error ...  the first span in `http://www.google.com` is empty and am not sure what else you expect

```
 <span class=gbtcb></span> <----------------  item(0)
 <span class=gbtb2></span> <----------------  item(1)
 <span class=gbts>Search</span> <-----------  item(2)
```

Try

```
$element = $doc->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(2);
var_dump($element->nodeValue);
```

Output

```
Search
```

Comment: yes, the output works, and i appreciate your answer yet my output on my server is "string(0) "" " so it's on my end, right?

Comment: very strange, others have reported the same problem . .

Comment: `var_dump(file_get_content("http://google.com"))` add the result to pastbin let me take a look at it  ...

Comment: returns an empty string for me. must be a configuration problem. works fine on the pastebin

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors','On');` on top of the page and try again

Comment: yes it is a server configuration issue. i tried it locally and it works fine; however, on my webhost is doesnt. im writing up an alternative cURL snippet for him now

Comment: i did several sites and it still returns empty

Comment: Add your `phpinfo` to pastbin let me see

Comment: And can you just restart `apache` and `php`

Answer (score 0):

First, bear in mind that the HTML is not necessarily valid XML.

That aside, check that you're actually getting some contents to parse; you need to have `allow_url_fopen` enabled in order to use `file_get_contents()` with URLs.

In general, avoid using the error suppression operator (@) because it will almost certainly come back to bite you some time (and this time might well be that time); there is a discussion on this [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php).

So, as a first step, switch to something like the following let me know if you're getting any contents at all.

```
// stop using @ to suppress errors
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// check that you're getting something to parse
echo $contents;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell us what the output is

```
<?
echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
?>
```

Comment: Ok so we can rule out that being the problem.

Comment: above, im confused how the codepad script works and on my server it doesnt :/

Answer (score 0):

Try using cURL to get the data and then load it into a DOMDocument:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($data); //The @ is necessary to suppress invalid markup

echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(2)->nodeValue;

if (0 != $element->length) 
{
    $content = trim($element->item(2)->nodeValue);
    if (empty($content)) 
    {
        $content = trim($element->item(2)->textContent);
    }
    echo $content . "\n";
}

?>
```