# MySQL Not Saving Record

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that currently has "**438,442**" rows. The next AutoIncrement is "**854,040**"

My clients sometimes report that their record does not save. Though system says it does but when they get back later, the record was not there.

So I wanted to ask if the problem is due to high number of records in the table or something similar ?

I am using standard PHP function to insert MySQL:

```
$Qry = "INSERT INTO lesson_result (user, marks, grade, date) VALUES ( 23127, 88, 'B', '2012-11-25')";
$isInserted = @mysql_query($Qry) or die(mysql_error());
```

Another thing I found while I was checking MySQL Runtime Information using PhpMyAdmin is:

> **Table_locks_waited : 2,298**

Can we consider this as the cause of problem?

Comment: can you show your code so that we  can help you

Comment: Do you have a `TRANSACTION` that's started but not committed?

Comment: @D3 K : I do not think it's for the records, could you please show a piece of code about that?

Comment: I have updated my question with the code, that I am using to insert. This is the working code.
It has been working perfectly. But from the past few months, I have started receiving random complaints about not saving their results!

Comment: For one thing I don't think you should ever use @ (like Gerry, I've yet to see a proper use). Again, not an expert, but I don't think you should use `mysql_` function... deprecated and unsafe. Use `mysqli_` or `pdo`, although I know this isn't always possible in a commercial environment.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php

Comment: Thanks Raeki for your comments. The system was bit old. So I have to stay with until we build something new. Any ideas about the question ???