# How to properly increment some array key, even if key needs to be created?

Tags: php, optimization, micro-optimization

Suppose you need to create a 'top' of some sort and have code like this:

```
$matches=array();
foreach ($array as $v){
   $matches[processing($v)]++;  
}
```

This will output a **`Notice: Undefined index`** for the cases the index needs creating.

What would be the best way to tackle these cases since you KNOW you'll have to create indexes?

I used these solutions depending on case:

1. Suppressing the error `@$matches[$v]++;`
   **Pro**: VERY easy to type
   **Con**: slow
2. Checking if it's set `$matches[$v]=isset($matches[$v])?$matches[$v]++:1;`
   **Pro**: faster
   **Con**: takes longer to write even in the shorthand form and need to use $matches[$v] 2 more times

Are there any other ways?
Looking for the **fastest execution time** as I'm using this function thousands of times or some **lazier way to type** that's still faster than @

**EDIT:**

In a simple case where you have `$matches[$v]++;` you could also use `array_count_values()` *(as Yoshi suggested)*

Comment: try [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/function.array-count-values.php): `$matches = array_count_values($array);`

Comment: I don't see how (2) can be faster than (1), given that (2) performs the same calls as (1) and then some (a conditional and `isset`).

Comment: @Yoshi: good one, thank you, updated my question. I'm doing some processing inside the loop and can't count that simple.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: you'd think that but it appears `isset()` is faster: [benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7200025/731947)

Comment: @TheOptometrist if `processing($v)` allways returns the same value for the same `$v`, then you could still use `array_count_values` and apply `processing()` on the keys of the resulting array. ;)

Comment: @TheOptometrist I'm a bit curious, how would you use the multiple values returned from `processing()` as array key? php would try to convert those values to a string before using them as a key, which could possible cause problems!?

Comment: Also, regarding your comment to Marc's answer. I wouldn't know of any value you could possible return from a function, which you can't assign to a variable!?

Comment: @Yoshi: indeed you could assign the value of a function to any var, I gave the 'processing()' as an example when actually I have a while inside it that increments the array key based on some if's so it's not actually `$matches[processing($v)]++`, just wrote it like that for simplicity and to emphasize on the increment part. actually it doesn't matter what the function does as this question is aimed at a fast increment of *possible* non-indexed arrays for very large datasets

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some reading, writing and testing I got something:

```
function inc(&$var){
    if (isset($var)) $var++;else $var=1;
}
```

and thought I struck gold, but let's see the tests first...

### Test code:

```
$a=array();

// Pre-Fill array code goes here
for($i=1;$i<100000;$i++) {
    $r=rand(1,30000);
    //increment code goes here
}

// Remove extra keys from array with:
//foreach ($a as $k=>$v) if ($v==0) unset($a[$k]);
```

Execution times: *(for informative purposes only)*

```
inc($a[$r])                             1.15-1.24
@$a[$r]++                                   1.03-1.09
$a[$r]=array_key_exists($r,$a)?$a[$r]++:1;  0.99-1.04

$a[$r]=!empty($a[$r])?$a[$r]++:1;               0.61-0.74
if (!empty($a[$r])) $a[$r]++;else $a[$r]=1; 0.59-0.67
$a[$r]=isset($a[$r])?$a[$r]++:1;                0.57-0.65
if (isset($a[$r])) $a[$r]++;else $a[$r]=1;  0.56-0.64


//with pre-fill
$a=array_fill(0,30000,0);                   +0.07(avg)
for($i=1;$i<=30000;$a[$i++]=0);             -0.04(avg)

//with pre-fill and unset
$a=array_fill(0,45000,0);                   +0.16(avg)
for($i=1;$i<=45000;$a[$i++]=0);             +0.02(avg)
```

### Conclusions:

- `@` is of course the fastest to type and I don't see any problem in using it **in this case** but feel free to check this question also: [Suppress error with @ operator in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/136899/731947)
- completely suppressing errors (before the loop and enabling errors after the loop) via `ini_set()` is worse than all on performance
- `inc()` looks nice and clean, easy to type and does checking instead of suppressing, but calling it looks to be even slower than `@`
- `isset()` is slightly faster than `empty()`, but both perform fairly the same
- interestingly using **shorthand** `if` statements is **slightly slower**!
- best results achieved when pre-filling the array. Even if length is unknown a good prediction would be still slightly faster on a huge dataset
- strangely, `array_fill()` takes slightly longer than `for` ?!?!

### RFC

I don't consider this answer 100% complete, although, for now it looks like `isset()` is the fastest and `@` the laziest.
Any comments and ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Your shorthand `if` might have been slower because of an extra assignment - you do a redundant `$a[$r]=$a[$r]++`. I suppose it should be more equivalent to the normal `if` if you dropped the left side and did just `isset($a[$r]) ? $a[$r]++ : $a[$r]=1;`

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps initialise the matches array to begin with, using `array_combine` to combine the values from `$array` as keys and `array_fill` to fill the values with an initial 0

```
$matches = array_combine(array_values($array), array_fill(0, count($array), 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I always do:

```
$matches=array();

foreach ($matches as $v){

    /* if $v is not empty, add 1, otherwise $v= 1 */
    $matches[$v]=(!(empty($matches[$v]))) ? $matches[$v]++ : 1;
}
```

You're right. It's a little wordy but to be fair it's quite succinct at the same time. I use `empty()` instead of `isset()` though. Not sure if that's faster or slower off the top of my head. I think it's probably slower.

**Edit**

To answer your edit, I'd do it like this:

```
$matches=array();

foreach ($matches as $v){

    $x=function($v);

    /* if $v is not empty, add 1, otherwise $v= 1 */
    $matches[$x]=(!(empty($matches[$x]))) ? $matches[$x]++ : 1;
}
```

That way, you only call the function once.

Comment: `!empty()` is pretty much like `isset()` to write, would worth it only  if it would be faster

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7+ solution:

```
$arr[$key] = ($arr[$key] ?? 0) + 1;
```