# Simulated Ruby symbols in PHP

Tags: php

Ruby and some other languages have a very convenient feature: symbols. They look like in-place constants. Now I wonder if the following approach by simulating symbols in PHP with [an at sign](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) before an unquoted string is a valid approach.

```
$array = [@key => "value"];
echo sprintf("%s PHP symbols with a %s\n", @testing, $array[@key]);
```

I understand there are certain drawbacks against formal constants and the like, which are same as for Ruby's symbols: consider typing errors. Are there any other considerations against using this approach?

Comment: By the by -- in case you were wondering, symbols are a port from Common Lisp.

Comment: Why don’t you use Ruby in the first place?

Comment: @Gumbo loads of legacy code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suppressing an error (a notice, to be exact). not only this costs processing time as mentioned in cwallenpoole's answer, but also the error is there for a reason. The reason is:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant hello - assumed 'hello' in ...
```

**You are relying on some constant being undefined** - which is exactly what the notice is trying to tell you. If a constant of that name is defined, you will grab its value instead.

In Ruby, `:__LINE__` is something quite different from `__LINE__`. The former is a symbol - it equals itself no matter where you use it. The latter is a number, and a magical variable that changes its value on every line. In PHP, `@__LINE__` is the same as `__LINE__`, because there is no error to suppress. Oh, and there's one special "symbol" that is extra-fun to debug: `@exit`, AKA `@die`.

In Ruby, you can use all sorts of symbols including operators and keywords. These (and many more) are all valid: `:+` `:*` `:<` `:<<` `:[]` `:[]=` `:while` `:case` `:x=`. With a pair of parentheses, you can even use symbols like `:case=` and `:while=`. **In PHP, none of these work**. You'll end up with a parse error. It won't even be suppressed. The only exception is `@[]` in PHP 5.4, which produces an empty array. On the other hand, lots of PHP expressions are not valid Ruby symbols: `@(1+1) === @2` `@1 == @'1'`

Ruby's symbols are not equal to anything else. This is the purpose of their existence. Sure, they have some nice properites like `to_s` and `to_proc`, but their original purpose is to serve as identifiers separate from any possible user input. This is sorta nice for example if you are using symbols to represent tokens in a lexer stream, such as `[:lparen, 1, :plus, "rparen", :rparen]`. **In PHP, undefined constants are strings**. In Ruby, `?test != "test"`. In PHP `@test === "test"` (assuming you dindn't define a constant named "test" to equal something else).

**you can't even assume non-magic constants won't change**. You can't even attribute to malice what can be explained with bad coding. Nothing like that is of worry in Ruby:

```
//in library code:
$this->status = @done; // bad

//outside library code:
define('done', "no"); // very bad
define(@done, "yes"); // even worse
echo @no; // prints "yes"

//in library code:
if($this->status == @done){
  //won't execute
}

echo @die;
echo "this won't get printed!";
```

---

You shouldn't rely on constants being undefined, and you shouldn't use error suppressing to  hide the error messages telling you that. You shouldn't use special notation to pretend two things are not equal when they are. Also, can you trust the users of your library to not redefine constants at runtime?

Comment: Just as a note: `Ruby's symbols are not equal to anything else.` is not quite true. They are pretty darn close to the Lisp symbol. Just saying. But then, I am nit-picking. Good answer. +1.

Comment: @cwallenpoole I meant, to any other value (either a non-symbol or a symbol with a different text content), not, to any other concept in the computing world. Custom types serve the purpose of unique identifiers just fine, so the concept is not very new.

Comment: As I said, I was totally nitpicking.

Comment: Thank you for the good point on constants. In our code we don't use non-class constants, but if someone ever adds a constant with a right name, so to say, it'll wreak havoc. Where processing time isn't a serious issue, this one with constants is a real one.

Answer (score 3):

If by "valid" you mean "can be run", then yes, it is a valid approach (but by that standard, it is also valid to make all of your strings into HEREDOC's). But simply because PHP will accept the syntax, does not mean that the syntax is without problems.

The first I can think of are that

1. You are actively suppressing an error, which costs processing time
2. Your co-workers will need an explanation as to what is going on, which costs developer time
3. You are working against the natural definitions of the language (PHP simply isn't Ruby)
4. Since you have to use a sigil for variables anyway, you're not actually cleaning the code.

Comment: Points 1 and 2 will go away once this becomes a custom. Your third point isn't clear. Mind I ask you to go into details of the natural definitions you're mentioning?

Comment: @sanmai #1 will never go away unless PHP 6 makes allowance for it.

Comment: @sanmai #2 will never go away unless #1 goes away. (every time you introduce a new person to the project it will cost that person time to adjust)

Comment: @sanmai #3 means that "the language was written a certain way, so it should be used that way". As an extreme: you wouldn't use Java as a functional language.

Comment: 5. you can't use keywords as symbols. Also, functions of that name could cause trouble.

Comment: @JanDvorak please add an answer

Answer (score 2):

Warning:
The following answer contains analogies that are meant, purely to illustrate a point. Under *no* circumstances do I mean to even suggest you *contemplate* the possibility of someone (you or anyone else) actually sitting down and doing the things I mention. That way madness lies

---

Though other answers have explained the main issue with using `@<str>`, It supressing a notice, it's important to stress this a bit more.
When using the supressing `@` (of death) the notice *does not magically dissapear* it is still being issued. After a while logs will get clogged with notices, making it harder to find that one *fatal error* that could be in there. Even if there is no fatal error, it still slows the code down.

Why encourage people to write code that throws notices? Just because you like the ruby syntax? come on, if you don't like a language, don't use it. I know: legacy code, you have to... well then, do it, don't try to make it feel and look like Ruby. They're not the same language. Everything that reminds you of the fact that you're working with a different language should be seen like a tool. Different languages require different mindsets, and different ways of thinking about a problem.

Imagine writing Lisp, but change the syntax to SQL queries. How much *bad code* will that generate. The syntax forces you into an SQL mindset, whereas you should be thinking in functions.
*But for God's sake, don't that way madness lies!! It's a fools errand, it's even worse than parsing HTML with regex. It'll make even Cthulhu cry like a little girl*

Oh, and `@` *not* being used to supress errors once it's in common usage? Do you really believe that? So you expect a lot of people to write bad code, until some IDE plugin is released that doesn't complain about the abuse of the `@` sign. And then, you expect the PHP contributors to take notice, and find a new operator to supress errors? 
Honestly. I don't want to be rude, but that's like expecting Microsoft to release the source of windows8, because some people have gotten used to linux being open source.

Another thing: As I said, suppressing notices isn't going to help you when debugging the code. It's well known that PHP has way to many functions (and reserved keywords) in its core/global namespace. If you, and your co-workers get in the habit of abusing the `@` operator, you could just end up with code like this:

```
$foo[@die] = [@exit, @constant];
```

Have fun debugging that onholy mess of unclear errors. Honestly...

Comment: `Imagine writing Lisp, but change the syntax to SQL queries.`  I just gagged a little... That would truly be horrendous.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: I'm sorry. I don't know how I could think of something that perverted, I'd deserve to have my eyes poked out for that... I just got so worked up with this question. It's ok _not_ to like a language. Heck, I worked with COBOL for over a year, and hated every second of it, but I never once tried to force the language into behaving like something it wasn't. Just because you dress up an ape in a pretty frock, doesn't mean you can enter it for a beauty pageant. (that would have been a less sickening analogy).

Comment: Actually the worst part is the fact that I started thinking "You know, with the right use of macros..."

Comment: @cwallenpoole: Dear God no! I hope that didn't cause any permanent damage... Let me know how much the counselling cost, [because this isn't funny](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/ruby/)

Comment: "When using the supressing @ (of death) the notice does not magically dissapear it is still being issued. After a while logs will get clogged with notices" -- not true! If the error suppressing operator is used, no errors will be logged for that statement. The only issue is with custom error handlers that don't respect the error logging level - `@` works by setting this value to zero (no errors logged) temporarily.

Comment: You code sample works just fine. Until you replace `@explode` with `@die` or `@exit`

Comment: Sorry dude, I've already accepted an answer with `@die` before you made your edit

Comment: @sanmai: That's quite all right, I didn't assume this answer would be the one that got the accept vote, I just _had_ to react to the question that was being asked, that's all

Answer (score 0):

The `key` in your code would be seen by PHP as an unknown constant.

In most languages this would halt the compiler, but PHP mutates it into a string in an effort to keep running. It throws a warning, but keeps going anyway. This is just bad, and you really don't want to be doing it, much less doing it deliberately.

`@` in PHP is for suppressing errors. It does nothing else.

Your `@key` will still be bad practice just as `key` would be and would function in exactly the same way, but the `@` will hide the error message that would normally be generated.

Using `@` error suppression in PHP is bad practice for a whole bunch of reasons (<sup>‡</sup> see note below), but using it as a way to hide deliberately bad code is terrible. Please don't do this.

The fundamental point here is that you're using PHP, so you should write PHP code. Trying to write Ruby code in PHP is never going to work.

**You should work *with* the language you're using, not against it.**

*<sup>‡</sup> For some thoughts on why error suppression is bad practice, you may want to read this: [Suppress error with @ operator in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php)*

One final thought: This thing of PHP converting unknown constants to a string exists in the language purely for legacy compatibility reasons; it's one of the really awful bits of bad language design that date back to the early days. A lot of the other bad stuff from early PHP has been deprecated in recent versions; this hasn't yet, but there's no good reason for it still to exist, so I kinda hope they find a way to deprecate this "feature" too. If they do, that will instantly stop your idea from working, regardless of any merits it may have.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why this is a bad practice. See the accepted answer for the explanation.