# Run query from an input tag from a table that was returned by a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php function that is running a query and returning the data in a table.

```
 <?php
 function displayrecords() {
 $sql_json = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
 $QueryResult = @msql_query($sql_json) or die (mysql_error());
      echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">
      echo "<table>\n";
      while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE){
      echo "<tr><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete/Edit\" class=\"open-EditRow btn btn-primary btn-mini\" id=\"".$Row[pk_tId]."\" title=\"Edit this row\" /\"></td>";
```

As you see, I am wrapping the table in a form, and the first tr tag has an input tag. This is where I need to run a query from pk_tId, which is also retrieved from the same table called mytable. I just need to display it to the same screen, which is in a file called edit.php.

How can I run a second query from inside the function and print it to the screen?

Comment: [Don't use error suppression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/960288/164998).

Comment: So I take out: or die (mysql_error()): and then what?

Comment: @JohnBeasley and then [**don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *` in queries from your application, because you can't know for certain if the table structure will change during the lifetime of this code, and in this case you're only interested in one column anyway.

Comment: @Jeremy Smyth, that's an answer to a question I didn't ask. I don't mean to sound rude. It's just that there are 3 answers (so far) on this page, and all 3 answers are to questions I didn't ask. Ok, fine, I need to re-learn everything I've been taught. Understood. But the question I DID ask is not being answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is truly unclear, I am not sure if you want to retrieve the data upon a certain action, or if you just want to add another button. I am going to take a a big jump here and post what I think might be what you are looking for, if not than forgive me for my lack of this topics understanding. Also it is bad practice to use error suppression. See if this is what you are trying to achieve.

(Not tested)
Also I do suggest using a pdo class... but I guess you will figure that on your
own when the time comes.

```
  function showData ()
  {
    $q = mysql_query ("select * from mytable");
    $w = "";

    if (mysql_num_rows ($q) >= 1) {
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_row ($q)) {
            $w .= "<td>
                    data: {$rows ['pk_tId']}
                   </td>";
        }
    }return $w;
}

 function displayrecords ()
 {
    if (isSet ($_POST ['submit'])) 
    {
        $w = showData ();

    }else{

        $q = mysql_query ("select * from mytable");
        $w = "";

        if (mysql_num_rows ($q) >= 1) {
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_row ($q)) {
                $w .= "<td>
                        <input type='submit' value='Delete/Edit' class='open-EditRow btn btn-primary btn-mini' id='{$rows[pk_tId]}' title='Edit this row' name="submit">
                       </td>";
            }
        }
    }
    return $w;
}

<form action="" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php echo displayrecords (); ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```