# PHP Phar - file_exists() issue

Tags: php, include, require, file-exists, phar

My Phar script creates a new file with fwrite, which works fine, it creates the new file outside the phar, in the same directory as the phar file.

But then when i use if(file_exists('file.php')) it doesn't pick it up.

But then include and require do pick it up.

Anyone know about this problem?
Been testing and researching for a while a can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: What version of PHP? URL wrappers can on only verions =>PHP 5.0.0

Comment: Have you tried the following recommendation from the documentation for [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/file_exists): "Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details."?

Comment: yea, i've tried the clearstatcache() - but the cache would store it as 'exists' and my problem is that its not finding it - so that's definitely not the culprit.

Comment: Could give exmaple of your directory structure and location of scripts that are run, which include some other scripts and where do the writes end up.

Answer (score 7):

At the PHAR's stub, you can use the `__DIR__` magic constant to get the PHAR file's folder.

With that in mind, you can simply use

```
is_file(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

To check for a file's existence outside the PHAR.

You can ONLY do this from the stub, and ONLY if it's a custom stub, as opposed to one generated by Phar::setDefaultStub(). If you need to check for files further down the line, you'll have to make that constant's value available somehow, like a global variable, a custom non-magical constant or a static property or something, which other files then consult with.

EDIT: Actually, you can also use `dirname(Phar::running(false))` to get the PHAR's folder from anywhere in the PHAR. That function returns an empty string if you're not within a PHAR, so whether your application is executed as a PHAR or directly, it should work fine, e.g.

```
$pharFile = Phar::running(false);
is_file(('' === $pharFile ? '' : dirname($pharFile) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . $path)
```

Comment: Using `__DIR__` definitely doesn't work, not from a custom stub, not even a little bit.  It will return the current working directory of the phar and `__FILE__` will return the phar name.

Answer (score 6):

I meet the same issue today. After several hours digging ... I found the answer.

Can you try the following script first?

```
if(file_exists(realpath('file.php')));
```

If the file exist, then the issue is

if you use only the filename without path information, php treat file is related to phar stub. for example:

`phar:///a/b/c/file.php`

So, you have to use absolute path to manipulate the file, for example:

`/home/www/d/e/f/file.php`

Hope this help.

Mark

Answer (score 5):

## Working with file paths and Phar archives

Working with file paths and Phar archives in PHP can be tricky. The PHP code inside of a Phar file will treat relative paths as being relative to the Phar archive, *not* relative to the current working directory. Here's a short example:

Say you have the following files:

```
phar/index.php
test.php
my.phar
```

The index.php file is located inside of the phar directory. It is the bootstrap file for the phar archive:

```
function does_it_exist($file){
  return file_exists($file) ? "true" : "false";
}
```

The bootstrap file is executed when the phar file is included from a PHP script. Our bootstrap file will simply cause the function "does_it_exist" to be declared.

Let's try running different code inside of test.php and see what the results are for each run:

```
//Run 1:
require_once 'phar/index.php';  //PHP file
$file = __DIR__ . "/index.php"; //absolute path
echo does_it_exist($file);      //prints "false"

//Run 2:
require_once 'phar/index.php';  //PHP file
$file = "index.php";            //relative path
echo does_it_exist($file);      //prints "false"

//Run 3:
require_once 'my.phar';         //phar file
$file = __DIR__ . "/index.php"; //absolute path
echo does_it_exist($file);      //prints "false"

//Run 4:
require_once 'my.phar';         //phar file
$file = "index.php";            //relative path
echo does_it_exist($file);      //prints "true"
```

Look at Run 4. This code includes the phar file and passes the function a relative path. Relative to the current working directory, index.php does not exist. But relative to the contents of the phar archive, it does exist, which is why it prints "true"!

Comment: i know, i know. thats not the question.    my phar package creates a new file OUTSIDE of the phar script using fwrite. that works perfectly, a new file is created. and this new can later be read by include or require but it cant be "seen" by file_exists - which is my problem - i think it might be a bug in phar

Comment: @Lan replied you query

Comment: thanks, but if include('login.php') or require('login.php') both find and read the file, than surely if(file_exists('login.php')) would return true - surely by the fact that its read by include/require shows the file path/location is correct, and so that is not the issue?

Comment: @Lan Changed the answer to understand the working more easily

Comment: hey thanks man, i think i'm starting to see what your saying. But my problem is that WITHIN my phar file, i want to check for a file OUTSIDE of it. when i run my phar file it creates 'login.php' in the same directory as the phar, but outside of it. then when you run the phar again, i need it to check if that login.php is there, outside. what file path do i use for that?

Comment: I don't know what r u trying to do as it depends of the code but the trick to do thing is provided

Comment: This answer was lifted from http://mangstacular.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/php-relative-paths-and-phar-archives.html

Answer (score 2):

`file_exists` in php has several issues, in particular cases.

I recommend you to use [`stat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) instead, which is commonly preffered way to obtain that info,
not just in php. Also don't forget to clear the cache by calling [`clearstatcache()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php).

```
function FileExists($filename)
{
    clearstatcache(false, $filename);
    
    return false !== @stat($filename);
}
```

Note : I try to avoid the suppress operator `@` as much as I can but I see this particular case as neccessary to use it :)

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this behavior by calling [`Phar::interceptFileFuncs()`](http://php.net/phar.interceptfilefuncs). It seems `fopen` calls in write mode are not intercepted, while stat-related functions are.

Since absolute filenames are treated as related to the filesystem even in Phar archives that intercept file functions:

> [...] Absolute paths are assumed to be attempts to load external files from the filesystem.

...one way to deal with the problem is to use [`realpath()`](http://php.net/realpath):

```
if (file_exists(realpath($filename)) { /* file exists on filesystem */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is causing `file_exists()` to fail but you can try something like this

```
 function fileExists($path){
    //try to open the file, if it can be read the file exist
    return (@fopen($path,"r") == true); 
 }
```

Comment: ahh good idea. thanks. do i need to fclose it afterwards to keep it more legit?

Comment: Yes ofcourse! You can close it afterwards if the fopen function succeed. Open the file, if it succeed close the file and return true, else return false.