# difference between $variable and @$variable in php

Tags: php, curl, domdocument

Can you please tell me the difference between 
$variable and @$variable in php

```
<?php
 curl function abc
{
 get information of url and return information string
}
$html=abc();
$doc=DOMDocument();
@$doc->LoadHTML($html); 
?>
```

here if we take normal variable it gives error why its so
and whats the difference

Comment: `@` is used as error suppressor http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: @ prevent php to give error.

Comment: Really don't use that thing. Now you know what it does please remove it from your code and use [`libxml_use_internal_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `@` before a function call means "suppress warnings".

So, `@$doc->LoadHTML($html);` suppresses warnings from the method call (`LoadHTML()`).

In general this is a **bad idea**, because the warnings mean you are doing something wrong, and you would better fix that instead of playing deaf.

Answer (score 1):

The `@` operator tells the compiler to ignore the error that PHP could give, its advised not to use it.

Comment: but when i not use it i got an error

Answer (score 1):

Suppress warning when accessing that property, if for instance $html was undefined then no error is displayed, see http://davidwalsh.name/suppress-php-errors-warnings

Answer (score 0):

@ is called [`Error Control Operator`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), it can be prepended before expression to disable error reporting for that expression.

Please see this post for more information: [Suppress error with @ operator in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php)