# php form not sending to email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Hi i have creating my form and this is the php script

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "malsl3@aol.com";

    $email_subject = "KwikDrive Rentals Customer Message";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br /></a>";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['firstname']) ||

        !isset($_POST['lastname']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['message'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['firstname']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['lastname']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // required

    $comments = $_POST['message']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

      $telephone_exp = '/^((\(?0\d{4}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|(\(?0\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|(\(?0\d{2}\)?\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$/';

    if(!preg_match($telephone_exp,$telephone)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Telephone you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



<p>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon. </p>
<p><a href="bookingform2.php">Click here if you wish to return to the contact page.<br /><br />
</a></p>
<?php

}

?>
```

It was working fine at the start sending to this email address but when i change email address to enquiries@kwikdrive.com it would not send. ive changed it back to malsl3@aol.com and im not recieving to that email anymore either. its says form submitted but no email comes through. malsl3 email was just for test purposes but enquiries@kwikdrive.com is the one i need tested. you can check the form at kwikdrive.com/contacts.php

Comment: I am now recieving email to malsl3@aol.com.I have now changed the email to enquiries@kwikdrive.com but they still sending to malsl3@aol.com. really confused now

Answer (score -1):

Change `@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);`  to `mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);`

As far as I know @mail does not exist, only mail() does.

Comment: changed the mail thing but still no luck

Comment: Try to debug it, print the four variables , and try to use mail() using strings and not variables so you can check your serveur has no problem with sending mails. Some mutualized servers have issues sometimes..

Comment: `@` is an error suppressor. https://stackoverflow.com/q/136899/2943403  https://derickrethans.nl/five-reasons-why-the-shutop-operator-should-be-avoided.html