# Read IP address from file

Tags: php

Example 1

```
<?php
function Piso()
{

  $ip = '77.1.1.1.1';
  $ip2 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  return ($ip == $ip2);
}
?>
```

Example 2

```
<?php
function Piso()

  {
      $ip = fopen("bune.txt", "r");
      $ip2 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

      return ($ip == $ip2);
    }
    ?>
```

I want to read IP address from file bune.txt. If i read it == doesnt work. If i put ip address like example one, it works. But i need example 2 to work. 
Example two doesnt work, but i dont know how to read it to can $ip == $ip2. Thanks.

Comment: `fopen` does not read file contents. It just *sets you up* for reading. If you want an one-stop-shop for reading, use `file_get_contents` instead. As an aside, you should have tried `var_dump($ip)` immediately after you got your first unexpected result.

Comment: Doesnt work with file_get_contents too, i check it more then 5 times :)
$ip = file_get_contents('bune.txt', true);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there is only 1 IP address and nothing else in the file:

```
$ip = trim(file_get_contents("bune.txt"));
```

Comment: If you want to ensure you got an IP in either IPv4 or IPv6. Read the docs [Validation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)
    if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        echo "Valid IP!";
    }else{
       echo "Invalid IP!";
    }
?>

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
function Piso()

  {
      $ip = file_get_contents("bune.txt");
      $ip2 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

      return ($ip == $ip2);
    }
?>
```

Comment: @michaelbn: ha, it was from the OP question.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yep, but I read this and accept as right for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is because PHP's [`fopen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) function returns a file handle (type [`resource`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)) to read (because you passed `"r"`) as stream from the file.

Instead of `fopen()` use the simple function [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) which will return the content of the file.

```
function Piso() {
    // Absolute path is faster.
    $file = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "bune.txt";

    // Confirm that the file exists and is readable.
    if (is_readable($file) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    // Use trim() to remove white space and compare read IP against remote address.
    return (trim(file_get_contents($file)) == $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is similar to my, but You prefer to return result in 1 line. That's good, I like it, but in this way, i think we should use @ before file_get_content ;)

Comment: That's a hack, you should never use it. I extend my answer.

Comment: Why I should not use native PHP error's silincer? Your code looks like production edition, my - dev. In production You should not show any info to potential hacker, so..

Comment: he's testing at the place of just hiding errors, if the file is readable file_get_contents won't return an error. dev or production you should repair errors not hide them

Comment: @CodeBird You should repair errors before production. At production You must (yeah, must) hide language's errors and catch every error with Your error-logger. If You show Your file structure to hacker - this is a first leak.

Comment: CodeBird is absolutely right with what he wrote. You should suppress error displaying globally (via your `php.ini`) and not within your code. It even makes your code slower. Here are some things to read for you: http://www.sitepoint.com/why-suppressing-notices-is-wrong/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php