# Why can't I use the '@' operator inside of strings?

Tags: php

I have a variable that sometimes doesn't exist that I want to use inside of a string (or heredocs).

My code is like this:

```php
if(someExternalThings()) {
    $variable = 'value';
}

echo "I have a {$variable}";
```

The code works fine when `someExternalThings()` is true, but if it doesn't, PHP throws an error, as expected.

Since I know that variable won't break anything (other than inside of the strings) I decided to add `@` before it.

```php
echo "I have a {@$variable}";
```

But it outputs: `I have a {@}` and throws an error.

---

I fixed this by doing this:

```
$variable = @$variable;
echo "I have a {@$variable}"

//outputs: I have a {@} and throws no errors
```

Or by putting the entire `echo` inside of the if that checks `someExternalThings()`

```php
if(someExternalThings()) {
    $variable = 'value';
    echo "I have a {$variable}";
}
```

---

This kinda confuses me since we can use these...

```php
echo "{$foo->bar[0]}";
echo "{${foo::bar}}";
```

...and it just works fine.

Comment: why would you **ever** want to use `@` full stop?

Comment: @treyBake in an email address?

Comment: @jibsteroos not in the context of your question or in PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by full stop, @treyBake? Anyways, I figured that it would save some lines if I do that since the missing variable is harmless, it's just for appending some extra info or some sort in the string.

Comment: Never suppress errors - it's bad practice. Fix them instead. ..

Comment: It kinda smells bad to use ```@```, but using it like ```echo @"{$foo}"``` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @treyBake I'm not disagreeing with you. It smells bad.

Comment: @Kyrre then why the "but using it seems to do the trick" comment? o.O

Comment: Cus that's what OP asked for??? I'm not the morality police.

Comment: @Kyrre no, but at SO we like to offer best practices :)

Comment: I don't know where I learned this, but suppressing errors aren't "evil" if you know how to deal with them. My problem in my code is fixed anyway and I'm just asking **why** we can't use `@` inside of strings.  @Kyrre's comment works, btw

Comment: @0x4kgi [debugging agony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136899/suppress-error-with-operator-in-php)

Comment: @0x4kgi yes it is, if you know how to deal with them - fix them.

Comment: @treyBake, fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of '@' for 'silence errors' does not work for variables inside a string. It would work at the start of the statement, but it's much better to avoid the issue.

If you want to avoid an 'unknown variable' notice, you can set it to something. For example:

```
<?php
$variable = '';
if(someExternalThings()) {
    $variable = 'value';
}
// now $variable always has a value, maybe empty, but it exists.

echo "I have a {$variable}";
```

If the echo should only happen when $variable has a value, then put it into the `if` condition.